# leetcode python syntax error reversed linked list

Tags: python, linked-list, reverse

I'm trying to write a reversed linked list on leet code and I keep getting a `Syntax error on line 37:   print(curr.data, end=" ")
I don't get what the problem is. my code is running just fine on vs code.
does anyone know what to do?

```
class Node:    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


def create_linked_list():
    nums = input("Enter numbers (space-separated): ").split()
    if not nums:
        return None

    head = Node(int(nums[0]))
    curr = head

    for num in nums[1:]:
        new_node = Node(int(num))
        curr.next = new_node
        curr = curr.next

    return head


def reverse_linked_list(head):
    prev = None
    curr = head

    while curr:
        next_node = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = next_node

    return prev


def display_linked_list(head):
    curr = head

    while curr:
        print(curr.data, end=" ")
        curr = curr.next

    print()


head = create_linked_list()

print("Original linked list:")
display_linked_list(head)


head = reverse_linked_list(head)


print("Reversed linked list:")
display_linked_list(head)
```

Comment: which one is line 37? ...or add the **full** error traceback

Comment: Your code work just fine, I tested it.

Comment: tried also with an online [compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/ehw0_vWbw) and it works

Comment: make sure your Python is 3, not 2

Comment: I ran your code, entered `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and got `Original linked list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Reversed linked list: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` which seems to work. What is your intended output?

Comment: That is not the code you subbmited on LeetCode, right? That challenge has a `ListNode` class, not `Node`, and it needs a class `Solution` with an instance method called `reverseList`, not a stand-alone `reverse_linked_list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get this syntax error if you posted your code having selected "Python" as language (which is backed by a Python 2.7 compiler), instead of "Python3".

The syntax `print(curr.data, end=" ")` is not compatible with Python 2, where `print` is not a function, but a statement. To do the same in Python 2, you would do:

```
    print curr.val,
```

(Note that LeetCode defines a `ListNode` class with a `val` attribute, not `data`).

In short, don't choose "Python" in the LeetCode UI, but "Python3".